# Unix command to convert multiple line data in a single line along with delimiter

Tags: shell, unix, sed, awk

Here is the actual file data:

```
abc
def
ghi
jkl
mno
```

And the required output should be in this format:

```
'abc','def','ghi','jkl','mno'
```

The command what I used to do this gives output as:

```
abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno
```

The command is as follows:

```
sed -n 's/[0-3]//;s/ //;p' Split_22_05_2013 | \
  awk -v ORS= '{print $0" ";if(NR%4==0){print "\n"}}'
```

Comment: Hi. And what is your question? Which specific problem do you have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In response to sudo_O's comment I add an `awk` less solution in pure bash. It does not exec any program at all. Of course instead of `<<XXX ... XXX` (here-is-the-document) stuff one could add `<filename`.

```
set c=""
while read w; do
  echo -e "$c'$w'\c"
  c=,
done<<XXX
abc
def
ghi
jkl
mno
XXX
```

Output:

```
'abc','def','ghi','jkl','mno'
```

An even shorter version:

```
printf -v out ",'%s'" $(<infile)
echo ${out:1}
```

Without the horrifying pipe snakes You can try something like this:

```
awk 'NR>1{printf ","}{printf "\x27%s\x27",$0}' <<XXX
abc
def
ghi
jkl
mno
XXX
```

Output:

```
'abc','def','ghi','jkl','mno'
```

Or an other version which reads the whole input as one line:

```
awk -vRS="" '{gsub("\n","\x27,\x27");print"\x27"$0"\x27"}'
```

Or a version which lets awk uses the internal variables more

```
awk -vRS="" -F"\n" -vOFS="','" -vORS="'" '{$1=$1;print ORS $0}'
```

The `$1=$1;` is needed to tell to `awk` to repack `$0` using the new field and record separators (`OFS`, `ORS`).

Comment: +1 for not needless spawning sub-processes. Note that not using a space after `-v` isn't portable.

Comment: @sudo_O: Thanks for the comment! I did not know about the space issue! On linux and HP-UX is works without it.

Comment: @sudo_O: At the end I eliminated `awk` as well. :)

Comment: I prefer the `awk` solution haha ;)

Comment: @sudo_O: What a pervert! ;)

Comment: @PavanDongray: The pleasure is mine! And the Oscar goes to ...? ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat test.txt
abc
def
ghi
jkl
mno

$ cat test.txt | tr '\n' ','
abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno,

$ cat test.txt | awk '{print "\x27" $1 "\x27"}' | tr '\n' ','
'abc','def','ghi','jkl','mno',

$ cat test.txt | awk '{print "\x27" $1 "\x27"}' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$//'
'abc','def','ghi','jkl','mno'
```

The last command can be shortened to avoid [UUOC](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html):

```
$ awk '{print "\x27" $1 "\x27"}' test.txt | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$//'
'abc','def','ghi','jkl','mno'
```

Comment: This seems to be missing the quotes, still.

Comment: @miku i want the output as 'abc','def','ghi','jkl','mno'

Comment: @PavanDongray: Edited: Added quotes.

Comment: @miku - Some people don't like `cat file | other_command `. They prefer `other_command file`. +1 anyway.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I love pipes.

Comment: Uh... The `awk ... | tr ... | sed ...` is fairly impressive, but a little bit pointless. `Awk` can handle this.

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed` alone:

```
sed -n "/./{s/^\|\$/'/g;H}; \${x;s/\n//;s/\n/,/gp};" test.txt
```

Edit: Fixed, it should also work with or without empty lines now.

Comment: It depends on the last line actually - if last line of data ends with newline it will work. Otherwise you swap two blocks of code and make it `s/^\|\$/'/g;H;\${x;s/\n//;s/\n/,/gp}` instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat file 
abc
def
ghi
jkl
mno

$ cat file | tr '\n' ' ' | awk -v q="'" -v OFS="','" '$1=$1 { print q $0 q }'
'abc','def','ghi','jkl','mno'
```

1. Replace '\n' with ' ' -> (tr '\n\ ' ')
2. Replace each separator (' ' space) with (',' quote-comma-quote) ->
   (-v OFS="','")
3. Add quotes to the begin and end of line -> (print q $0 q)

Answer (score 2):

This can be done pretty briefly with sed and paste:

```
<infile sed "s/^\|\$/'/g" | paste -sd,
```

Or more portably (I think, cannot test right now):

```
sed "s/^\|\$/'/g" infile | paste -s -d , -
```

Comment: ur command worked fine after removing infile from cmd ie `sed "s/^\|\$/'/g" <i/P file> | paste -s -d , -`

Comment: @PavanDongray: I see, I have moved `infile` to be an argument to sed in the portable version. The `<infile` notation should work with most newer shells.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed "s/[^ ][^ ]*/'&',/g" input.txt | tr -d '\n'
'abc','def','ghi','jkl','mno',
```

To clean the last `,`, throw in a

```
| sed 's/,$//'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'seen == 1 { printf("'"','"'%s", $1);} seen == 0 {seen = 1; printf("'"'"'%s", $1);} END { printf("'"'"'\n"); }'
```

In slightly more readable format (suitable for `awk -f`):

```
# Print quote-terminator, separator, quote-start, thing
seen == 1 { printf("','%s", $1); }
# Set the "print separator" flag, print quote-start thing
seen == 0 { seen = 1; printf("'%s", $1}; }
END { printf("'\n"); } # Print quote-end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 perl -l54pe 's/.*/\x27$&\x27/' file
```